# XHTML-список + js

Tags: javascript

Необходимо, чтобы по щелчку на элементе списка, в окно alert выводилось содержимое атрибута "номер" элемента списка. Ниже код, который не работает! Большая просьба к спецам в js помочь.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>Вывод содержимого элемента списка</head>
  <body>
      <ul>
        <li number="1">Первый</li>
        <li number="2">Второй</li>
      </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var li_elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
      for (i = 0; i < li_elements.length; i++) {
          li_elements[i].onclick = function () {
              alert(this.number);
          }
      }
    </script>
  </body>   
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Атрибут стоит получать через специальный метод!

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>Вывод содержимого элемента списка</head>
  <body>
      <ul>
        <li number="1">Первый</li>
        <li number="2">Второй</li>
      </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var li_elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
      for (i = 0; i < li_elements.length; i++) {
          li_elements[i].onclick = function () {
              alert(this.getAttribute("number"));
          }
      }
    </script>
  </body>   
</html>
```